# Analysing interleaved DC-DC boost converter

Tags: power-electronics

[image: Here S2 is already ON and S1 is turned on]
I don’t know why the current does not pass through NP2 (I think the current through Lm2 would have magnetised the primary winding Np2 already) and if someone could help on analysing this circuit it would be of great.Thank you

Source: https://jit.yuntech.edu.tw/2021/JIT-V03N01-06.pdf

Comment: You need to ask a question. This is a Q and A site. Requesting generalized help without any attempt to solve this yourself or, without any indication of where you are stuck won't cut-the-mustard here. Also, any picture you embed needs to have a citation as to where it comes from. You need to do this.

Comment: That depends on Vgs2 not shown

Comment: @Andy aka I’m new to this site and I did solve this but I don’t know why the current does not flow through Np2. I tried to reason like the magnetising current through Lm2 would have caused that. But I’m not sure.

Comment: @Tony Stewart they didn’t care much about that it seems

Comment: “They” should care

Comment: @Tony Stewart I added the link for that given publication. I mean for analysing of the circuit nothing was mentioned. Anyway have a look at that publication and let me know. Thanks 

Comment: TL:DR must be related to tightly coupled chokes

Comment: @Tony Stewart thank you much. Let me spend some time in that.